# Live Stream for windows mobile app

Tags: windows-mobile, rtmp, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, m3u8

I am new to windows mobile application development. I want to develop an application to play live stream on Windows mobile devices. I have both formats HLS(.m3u8) and RTMP of streams available. Please guide me to some useful player for integration open source preferably (if available)

Thanks

Comment: What kind of mobile device are you going to use? Different ones do different things. What operating system are you going to be developing on (i.e. Windows, Android)? What environment are you going to be developing with (i.e. Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this project](http://phonesm.codeplex.com/) helpful to get HLS running on Windows Phone. If you really mean Windows Mobile, which is deprecated, you probably would need to use the libav libraries.

RTMP is terrible, try to forget that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Player Framework: an open source media player framework for Windows and Windows Phone

http://playerframework.codeplex.com/